# Drawing an arrow that is equidistant between two nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following code, I have an arrow drawn vertically. I would like the tail of it to be the same distance from the southern border of the node labeled `(-2,1)` as the head of it is from the northern border of the node labeled `0/1`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize}]

%A sequence of graphs is drawn, starting with the vertex labeled (-2,1).
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$(-2, 1)$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};


%An arrow is drawn to the next diagram.
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (-4,-0.75) -- (-4,-2);

\draw (-4,-3) -- (-2,-3);
\draw[fill] (-4,-3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-3) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){$(-2, 1)$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){$(-1, 0)$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-3,-3) +(0,-0.1)$){$2$};


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the nodes names, and draw the arrow between them. If you shorten the arrow, shorten it symmetrically.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0,
font=\scriptsize},shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}]

%A sequence of graphs is drawn, starting with the vertex labeled (-2,1).
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north] (A)  at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$(-2, 1)$};
\node[anchor=south]   at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};



\draw (-4,-3) -- (-2,-3);
\draw[fill] (-4,-3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-3) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){$(-2, 1)$};
\node[anchor=south] (B) at ($(-4,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){$(-1, 0)$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-3,-3) +(0,-0.1)$){$2$};
%An arrow is drawn to the next diagram.
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If we add

```
\fill[red,opacity=0.5] (A.south) circle[radius=1pt] (B.north) circle[radius=1pt] ([yshift=-7.5pt]A.south) circle[radius=1pt] ([yshift=7.5pt]B.north) circle[radius=1pt];
```

we get

[image]

illustrating that the 7.5pt are taken off from an arrow that connects the borders of these nodes. The details of this can be found in the discussion of `\pgfpointshapeborder`, which starts on p. 1123 of pgf manual v3.1.4.

Notice that IMHO you'd be way better off if you used `positioning` instead of all these explicit coordinates.

Comment: How would I specify that the tail of the arrow begins `7.5pt` from the southern border of the node containing `(-2,1)` and ends `7.5pt` from the northern border of the node containing `0/1`?

Comment: @user74973 Just use `shorten=7.5pt`. You may perhaps want to subtract the inner width, then `shorten=2.5pt`. I updated the code.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}` option. With `inner sep=0` as an option to the `TikZ` diagram and `shorten=7.5pt` as an option to the `\draw[-latex]` command, what is the distance between the borders of the nodes and the arrows? Is it `7.5pt` or `10pt`?

Comment: @user74973 I missed the fact that there was a `nner sep=0` in the code. `shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}` is just a style definition that makes it easier to symmetrically shorten the arrow. If you uses `shorten=7.5pt`, the distance will be 7.5pt. You can convince yourself by adding `\fill[red,opacity=0.5] (A.south) circle[radius=1pt] (B.north) circle[radius=1pt]
([yshift=-7.5pt]A.south) circle[radius=1pt] ([yshift=7.5pt]B.north) circle[radius=1pt];` to the code.

Comment: Doesn't this command draw an arrow `7.5pt` or `10pt` from the centers of the nodes labeled `A` and `B`?

Comment: @user74973 Where do the 10pt come from? No, this command draws the arrow 7.5pt from then node boundaries, not centers. If you draw an arrow between two extended (node) objects with Ti*k*Z, it will find the appropriate points on the *boundaries* of these shapes and connect them. If you wish to connect the centers, you need to say something like `\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=10pt] (A.center) -- (B.center);`.

Comment: I will get back to you within an hour. Thanks for your help. (I see that you added the code for coloring pink certain points on the borders of the nodes.)