# Consistency in distances between nodes on vertices along stacked, horizontal line segments in a `TikZ` diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following `TikZ` diagram, I have depicted an expanding graph - a sequence of simple graphs. An inconsistency in this diagram is the distances between consecutive steps in the expansion. For the first four steps, I just decreased the `y`-coordinate by `3` of each of the vertices. A multi-line node under a vertex of the fourth graph prevented that from happening. I just put the last graph `6 cm` under the fourth graph. It is unseemly.

How do I define a length between `(label_for_Vertex_b.south)` and `(label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b.north)` and use that distance to position the fraction `(2n+1)/2` on the last graph, and from this node, draw the last horizontal line?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize,
execute at begin node={\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.5ex}%
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0.5ex}}},
shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}]

%A sequence of graphs is drawn, starting with the vertex with the b-label b.


%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b.
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
%
\draw (-4,-3) -- (-2,-3);
\draw[fill] (-4,-3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-3) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) at ($(-2,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){$b - 1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
%
%An arrow is drawn to the next diagram.
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\vertex \textit{b}} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b);


%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b-1.
\draw (-4,-6) -- (-2,-6) -- (0,-6);
\draw[fill] (-4,-6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0,-6) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-6) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,-6) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-6) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
\node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1) at ($(-2,-6) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b-2) at ($(0,-6) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(0,-6) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
%
%
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\vertex $b - 1$} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1);


%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b-n.
\draw (-4,-9) -- (-2,-9) -- (0,-9) (2,-9) -- (5,-9);
\draw[fill] (-4,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\node at (1,-9){$\ldots$};
\draw[fill] (2,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (5,-9) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(0,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(0,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=south, green] (label_for_phantom_Farey_Fraction_at_ellipses) at ($(1,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(2,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b-n}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(2,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(5,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-(n+1)$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(5,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n+1}{1}$};
%
%
%
%
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-2) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\more vertices} (label_for_phantom_Farey_Fraction_at_ellipses);
%
%
%A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of last two vertices and the label of the mediants of these vertices.
\draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=3mm, shorten >=1mm] ($(3.5,-9) +(60:2)$) -- (3.5,-9);
\path node[anchor=south, align=center, text width={width("future vertex")}]
at ($(3.5,-9) +(60:2)$){future mediant\\for vertex\[\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\]};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of the edge between the last two vertices and its label.
\coordinate (label_for_Edge) at ($(3.5,-9.5) +(0,-0.75)$);
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (3.5,-9) -- (label_for_Edge);
\node[anchor=north, align=center, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] (actual_label_for_Edge) at (label_for_Edge)
{$\begin{aligned} &\text{Present edge label of} \\[-1.5ex]
&\quad 2\bigl[(b-n)+(b-(n+1))\bigr] \\[-1.5ex]
&\qquad=2^{2}b-(2n+1)2
\end{aligned}$};



\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\vertex $b - 1$} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1);


\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=30pt, shorten >=7.5pt] (label_for_Edge.south) -- ($(label_for_Edge.south) +(0,-4)$);

%Here is the vertex placed at the broken edge.
\draw (-4,-15) -- (-2,-15) -- (0,-15) (2,-15) -- (5,-15);
\draw[fill] (-4,-15) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-15) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0,-15) circle (1.5pt);
\node at (1,-15){$\ldots$};
\draw[fill] (2,-15) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] ({(2+5)/2},-15) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (5,-15) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-15) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,-15) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-15) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-15) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(0,-15) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(0,-15) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(2,-15) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b-n}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(2,-15) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(5,-15) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-(n+1)$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(5,-15) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n+1}{1}$};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of the edge between the last two vertices and its label.
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] ({(2+5)/2},-15) -- ({(2+5)/2},-16);
\node[anchor=north] at ({(2+5)/2},-16){$2^{2}b-(n+1)2$};
\node[anchor=south] (Last_Farey_Fraction_in_diagram) at ($({(2+5)/2},-15) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2n+1}{2}$};


%Extra code to display distances I want between graphs.
\draw[|<->|, green] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b) -- (label_for_Vertex_b);
\node[green, anchor=west] at ($($(label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b)!0.5!(label_for_Vertex_b)$) +(0.1,0)$){\textit{D}};
%
\draw[|<->|, green] ($(actual_label_for_Edge.south) +(0.5,0)$) -- ($(Last_Farey_Fraction_in_diagram.north) +(0.5,0)$);
\node[green, anchor=west] at ($($(actual_label_for_Edge.south) +(0.6,0)$)!0.5!($(Last_Farey_Fraction_in_diagram.north) +(0.6,0)$)$){\textbf{Want this to be \textit{D}}};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

\end{document}

Comment: I get errors `! Package pgf Error: No shape named label_for_Vertex_b-2 is known.` when running your MWE.

Comment: Somehow, `(label_for_Vertex_b-2)` was missing from the name for one of the nodes. The code has been edited.

Comment: Is this question related to your previous one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519117/consistency-in-drawing-point-a-tobend-right-30-point-b-in-a-tikz-diagr? There you have an answer, which solve your issues ...

Comment: @Zarko No. The code is the same, but the modifications requested in the posts are different. In the previous post, I wanted code to draw a bent arrow to the last graph. (I included the edited code in this post. The bent arrow ends just above a fraction typeset in green.) In the current post, I want to position the last graph … using the specification described in it.

Comment: But in my answer this is solved. Well, all is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

To shift complete blocks, you can put them in `scope`s,

```
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
 ...
\end{scope}
```

This allows you to shift the last block 3cm below the south anchor of the edge label.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize,
execute at begin node={\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.5ex}%
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0.5ex}}},
shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}]

%A sequence of graphs is drawn, starting with the vertex with the b-label b.


%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b.
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
%
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
 \draw (-4,0) -- (-2,0);
 \draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
 \node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) at ($(-2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b - 1$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
 %
 %
 %An arrow is drawn to the next diagram.
 \draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
 {Blow-up of\\vertex \textit{b}} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm]
 %Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b-1.
 \draw (-4,0) -- (-2,0) -- (0,0);
 \draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
 \node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1) at ($(-2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b-2) at ($(0,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(0,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
\end{scope} 
%
%
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\vertex $b - 1$} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1);

\begin{scope}[yshift=-9cm]
%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b-n.
 \draw (-4,0) -- (-2,0) -- (0,0) (2,0) -- (5,0);
 \draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \node at (1,0){$\ldots$};
 \draw[fill] (2,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (5,0) circle (1.5pt);
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(0,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(0,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=south, green] (label_for_phantom_Farey_Fraction_at_ellipses) at ($(1,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b-n}};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(5,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-(n+1)$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(5,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n+1}{1}$};
 %
 %
 %
 %
 \draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-2) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
 {Blow-up of\\more vertices} (label_for_phantom_Farey_Fraction_at_ellipses);
 %
 %
 %A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of last two vertices and the label of the mediants of these vertices.
 \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=3mm, shorten >=1mm] ($(3.5,0) +(60:2)$) -- (3.5,0);
 \path node[anchor=south, align=center, text width={width("future vertex")}]
 at ($(3.5,0) +(60:2)$){future mediant\\for vertex\[\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\]};
 %
 %A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of the edge between the last two vertices and its label.
 \coordinate (label_for_Edge) at ($(3.5,-0.5) +(0,-0.75)$);
 \draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (3.5,0) -- (label_for_Edge);
 \node[anchor=north, align=center, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] (edge label) at (label_for_Edge)
 {$\begin{aligned} &\text{Present edge label of} \\[-1.5ex]
 &\quad 2\bigl[(b-n)+(b-(n+1))\bigr] \\[-1.5ex]
 &\qquad=2^{2}b-(2n+1)2
 \end{aligned}$};
\end{scope}


\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\vertex $b - 1$} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1);



\path ($(0,0|-edge label.south)+(0,-3)$) coordinate(auxp);
\begin{scope}[shift={(auxp)}]
 %Here is the vertex placed at the broken edge.
 \draw (-4,0) -- (-2,0) -- (0,0) (2,0) -- (5,0);
 \draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \node at (1,0){$\ldots$};
 \draw[fill] (2,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] ({(2+5)/2},0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (5,0) circle (1.5pt);
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(0,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(0,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b-n}};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(5,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-(n+1)$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(5,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n+1}{1}$};
 %
 %A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of the edge between the last two vertices and its label.
 \draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] ({(2+5)/2},0)
 -- ({(2+5)/2},-1);
 \node[anchor=north] at ({(2+5)/2},-1){$2^{2}b-(n+1)2$};
 \node[anchor=south] (f2n) at ($({(2+5)/2},0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2n+1}{2}$};
\end{scope}
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=30pt, shorten >=7.5pt] 
(label_for_Edge.south) -- (f2n.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517000/194703), you would possibly benefit greatly using `positioning` to position the blocks relative to each other. This answer is written under the assumption that there are some reasons why you do not want to use `positioning`.

Here is another attempt to make you happy. The trick is to put of these layers in `pic`s and to put the ("fake") pics in a matrix.

> The vertical distance between these layers/pics is entirely fixed by
>   `column sep`.

If you want to add annotations that should not alter the size of these pics, use either `overlay` or add them outside of the matrix. Examples for both can be found in the MWE

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize,
execute at begin node={\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.5ex}%
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0.5ex}}},
shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1},
pics/fpic/.style={code={#1}}]

%A sequence of graphs is drawn, starting with the vertex with the b-label b.

\matrix[row sep=4.5em]{%<- this defines the difference between pics
%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b.
\pic{fpic={%
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
}};\\
%
%
\pic{fpic={%
\draw (-4,0) -- (-2,0) coordinate(lcompare);
 \draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
 %
 \node[anchor=north] (bcompare) at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
 \node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) at ($(-2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b - 1$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
 }};\\
 %
 %
\pic{fpic={%
 %Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b-1.
 \draw (-4,0) -- (-2,0) -- (0,0);
 \draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
 \node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1) at ($(-2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b-2) at ($(0,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(0,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
}};\\
\pic{fpic={
%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b-n.
 \draw (-4,0) -- (-2,0) -- (0,0) (2,0) -- (5,0);
 \draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \node at (1,0){$\ldots$};
 \draw[fill] (2,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (5,0) circle (1.5pt);
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(0,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(0,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=south, green] (label_for_phantom_Farey_Fraction_at_ellipses) at ($(1,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b-n}};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(5,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-(n+1)$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(5,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n+1}{1}$};
 %
 %
 %
 %
 %
 %A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of last two vertices and the label of the mediants of these vertices.
 \draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=3mm, shorten >=1mm,overlay] ($(3.5,0) +(60:2)$) -- (3.5,0);
 \path node[anchor=south, align=center, text width={width("future
 vertex")},overlay]
 at ($(3.5,0) +(60:2)$){future mediant\\for vertex\[\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\]};
 %
 %A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of the edge between the last two vertices and its label.
 \coordinate (label_for_Edge) at ($(3.5,-0.5) +(0,-0.75)$);
 \draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (3.5,0) -- (label_for_Edge);
 \node[anchor=north, align=center, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] (edge label) at (label_for_Edge)
 {$\begin{aligned} &\text{Present edge label of} \\[-1.5ex]
 &\quad 2\bigl[(b-n)+(b-(n+1))\bigr] \\[-1.5ex]
 &\qquad=2^{2}b-(2n+1)2
 \end{aligned}$};
}};\\
\pic{fpic={
 %Here is the vertex placed at the broken edge.
 \draw (-4,0) -- (-2,0) -- (0,0) (2,0) -- (5,0);
 \draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (-2,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \node at (1,0){$\ldots$};
 \draw[fill] (2,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] ({(2+5)/2},0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw[fill] (5,0) circle (1.5pt);
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(0,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(0,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(2,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b-n}};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(2,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n}{1}$};
 %
 \node[anchor=north] at ($(5,0) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-(n+1)$};
 \node[anchor=south] at ($(5,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n+1}{1}$};
 %
 %A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of the edge between the last two vertices and its label.
 \draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] ({(2+5)/2},0)
 -- ({(2+5)/2},-1);
 \node[anchor=north] at ({(2+5)/2},-1){$2^{2}b-(n+1)2$};
 \node[anchor=south] (f2n) at ($({(2+5)/2},0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2n+1}{2}$};
}};\\
};
%An arrow is drawn to the next diagram.
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
 {Blow-up of\\vertex \textit{b}} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b);
%
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\vertex $b - 1$} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1);
%
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-2) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
 {Blow-up of\\more vertices} (label_for_phantom_Farey_Fraction_at_ellipses);
%
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\vertex $b - 1$} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1);
%
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=30pt, shorten >=7.5pt] 
(label_for_Edge.south) -- (f2n.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using the `scope` environment is what I want! (I had forgotten about it.)  I much prefer to keep the code using basic commands of `TikZ`. I only have a handful of diagrams that need to be typeset in my dissertation, and this is by far the most detailed of them. As this modification is the last one for this diagram, I would very much like to use the `scope` environment. This will keep the preamble in this file to little more than the `mathtools` and `tikz` packages.

Comment: The last arrow is still too long. I magnified the image to verify.

Comment: @user74973 The distance is set by `\path ($(0,0|-edge label.south)+(0,-3)$) coordinate(auxp);`, If you want some other distance, you need either to say `\path ($(0,0|-edge label.center)+(0,-3)$) coordinate(auxp);` or change `-3` to your preferred value. I do not know which distance you want.

Comment: I agree that that `\path ($(0,0|-edge label.south)+(0,-3)$);` should move the next `scope` environment `3cm` down ... but do you see that the distances between the `scope` environments are not the same?

Comment: @user74973 Yes, but I thought you *wanted* to increase the distance to make space for the edge label. If you replace the `-15` in your original code by `-12`, the distances are the same but the edge label does not fit. So I thought you wanted to have something in between. If you say which distances should be what, I can update the answer (but will be offline now for a while).

Comment: I like the `3cm` between the nodes of the first four graphs. So, I would like the same for the arrow going to the last graph.

Comment: Why doesn't `\path ($(0,0|-edge label.south)+(0,-3)$);` give "the proper" positioning for the last scope environment?

Comment: @user74973 I added another proposal.

Comment: Ha! Yes, I am happier. I will look at it more carefully later. At a glance, it does appear more consistent with the other vertical spacing ... but still not the same. And I don't know why the other code did not give the proper spacing.

Comment: I will be offline for awhile. I will look again this evening. Thanks.

Comment: By magnifying the image of the pdf file, it is apparent that the distance between the bottom of the node  ...  `2^{2}b- (2n+1)2` and the top of the numerator of the fraction `(2n+1)/2` is longer than the distances between the nodes of the other graphs. Why doesn't `\path ($(0,0|-edge label.south)+(0,-3)$);` give "the proper" positioning for the last scope environment?

Comment: @user74973 Please tell me precisely what you mean by proper positioning. Define it by stating which distances should coincide. "`2^{2}b- (2n+1)2` and the top of the numerator of the fraction `(2n+1)/2` is longer than the distances between the nodes of the other graphs." : *which* distances?

Comment: The distance between the "b" under the vertex in the first graph and the numerator of the fraction "0/1" above the first vertex in the second graph.

Comment: That is the distance that I want between the bottom of `2^{2}b - (2n+1)2` and the top of the numerator of the fraction `(2n+1)/2`.

Comment: @user74973 Sorry, I give up. This is a *huge* graph. You give me "That is the distance that I want between the bottom of 2^{2}b - (2n+1)2 and the top of the numerator of the fraction (2n+1)/2." It is next-to-impossible for me to parse this. I plan to come back when I have more time.

Comment: Using the `scope` environment, you seem to have separated the bottom of the "b" under the vertex in the first graph from the numerator of the fraction "0/1" in the second graph by `3cm`. I just want "the same separation" between the last two graphs. Why didn't `\path ($(0,0|-edge label.south) +(0,-3)$);` allow for a `3cm` separation?

Comment: @user74973 Could you please mark the labels and distances somehow such that I know what you are talking about? And/or cook down the diagram to something smaller? I have been trying to answer this and spend a considerable amount of time  but it seems that we are talking about different things.

Comment: OK. I will mark the diagram with what I described in my last comment. I will send you another comment when I have done so. I have to be offline soon. Instead of rushing it and risking making a mistake, I will do it this afternoon.

Comment: (I am pretty sure that this is the last modification for the graph.)

Comment: I just edited the post. The distances that I want to be the same are now marked on the diagram with `\draw[|<->|, green] (Point A.south) -- (Point B.north);`. I am sure the `3cm` between scope environments that you have been using would be fine to keep.

Comment: @user74973 I believe to have found a much simpler and more precise method: put the layers into ("fake") pics. Then they will be measured by Ti*k*Z and changing the vertical distance between them is as simple as changing `row sep`. (BTW, I reopened your question, which was closed by a user who linked it to a post where this user wrote an answer. This seems to be a new feature, and only users above a certain reputation you can see what happened. Needless to spell out what I think of this.)